# Http.post No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angularjs, http, http-headers, cors, access-control

So I'm trying to call a http.post request from angular to my MVC Account controller to execute the externallogin method. I keep getting the error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." So I did a bit of digging and it seems it has something to do with CORS.

```
 var chrome = 100;
    var width = 500;
    var height = 500;
    var left = (screen.width - width) / 2;
    var top = (screen.height - height - chrome) / 2;
    var options = "status=0,toolbar=0,location=1,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,left=" + left + ",top=" + top + ",width=" + width + ",height=" + height;
    window.open("about:blank", "login-popup", options);

    authService.externalLogin(provider, returnUrl).then(function (response) {

    })

var _externalLogin = function (provider, returnUrl) {
    _logOut();
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.post(
'/Account/ExternalLogin', {
    provider: provider,
    ReturnUrl: returnUrl
}).success(function (response) {
deferred.resolve(response);}).error(function (err, status) {
_logOut();
deferred.reject(err);});
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

So this goes into the controller and creates the corresponding path. But then when it finishes the method it produces the error without redirecting the open window.

I tried implementing the CORS using http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ but nothing changed. Could someone explain how to fix this?

Comment: had you enable Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * on our server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting some headers on your post request. For example some customization you can do:

```
app.run(function ($http) {
  // Sends this header with any AJAX request
  $http.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
  // Send this header only in post requests. Specifies you are sending a JSON object
  $http.defaults.headers.post['dataType'] = 'json'
});
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT: The following seemed to work (read comments below):

```
$http({ 
  url: '/Account/ExternalLogin', 
  dataType: 'json', 
  method: 'POST', 
  data: { 
    provider: provider, 
    ReturnUrl: returnUrl 
  }
});
```

Comment: So I tried adding this in the services js file like what you had given, but no luck. Gave me the same errors... Am I just adding these headers in the wrong location?

Comment: You're fine, this should go on your `app.js` but the location doesn't matter as long as it's being included in your main HTML file. This can be quite a difficult thing to debug. Two other things to try: Make sure you are running your angular app from a server (localhost) instead of just opening the .html file from your file system. Second, try also specifying the `$http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'` or whatever you are sending.

Comment: Oh! And something very important! Make sure you are also sending data in your post request! Like this
$http({
    url: '/Account.ExternalLogin',
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      provider: provider,
      ReturnUrl: returnUrl,
    },
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

}

Comment: Hmm. so if I do the following updates and I get the same errors. I don't think the $http.post and your method differ as it is able to get to the controller. After the controller it runs the dispose method is used and that is where it gets the error. I tried adding the custom headers to the Web.Config file but no luck either. Thanks!

Comment: Heh got it to work. After including your updates, I found some typo errors which really just screwed me up. Thanks

Comment: Oh great! Can you let me know what worked so I can update my answer?

Comment: $http({ url: '/Account.ExternalLogin', dataType: 'json', method: 'POST', data: { provider: provider, ReturnUrl: returnUrl, } Just typo with this statement needing Account/ExternalLogin and in my model was different. So nothing on your part really.